# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки "Привет"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки "Привет" в предложении: 
Не надо долгих приветсвий, достаточно сказать "Привет".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант оформления:

***Не надо долгих приветствий, достаточно сказать "привет".***

Слово ***привет*** можно писать по-разному в зависимости от ситуации, желания автора и используемой синтаксической конструкции:

1) Прямая речь: *Не надо долгих приветствий, достаточно сказать: **"Привет!"***

2) Дословное высказывание как член предложения (предложенный вариант). Возможно написание со строчной или прописной буквы.

Пример: Лишь бы посмотрел в лифте и **сказал « привет»** ― уже счастье невероятное, аж душа замирает. [Маша Трауб. Замочная скважина (2012)]

3) Иногда это слово может использоваться без кавычек в бессоюзном предложении (БСП):

Потом она подошла к двери и потянула за ручку. *Я ей сказал ― **привет**. Она мне сказала ― здравствуй.*  [Андрей Геласимов. Год обмана (2003)]

Comment: Простите, а если это предложение в диалоге?

Comment: Если участник диалога говорит "привет", то это обычное слово, входящее в прямую речь. Оформление делается по общим правилам для диалога http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160

Comment: Такая ситуация. Диалог между двоими: 
- Здравствуйте, многоуважаемая...
- Не надо долгих приветствий, достаточно сказать: "Привет!" 
Такая формулировка верна?

Comment: Да, здесь всё верно.